# Processing: Creating two 3D boxes and rotating

Tags: opengl, rotation, processing

I need to create two Boxes, which should both be rotating with the same speed in the same way, only their position should be different. All i got is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMua9.png

I have used the following code:

```
float rotatevalue;
void setup()
{
  rotatevalue = 0;
    size(500, 500, OPENGL);
  if (frame != null) {
    frame.setResizable(true);
  } 
}

void draw()
{
    background(245, 238, 184);
    fill(246, 225, 65);
    rotatevalue = rotatevalue + 2;
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/4, height/4);
    rotateX(radians(rotatevalue));
    rotateY(radians(rotatevalue));
    box(50);
    popMatrix();

    pushMatrix();
    translate(3*width/4, height/4);
    rotateX(radians(rotatevalue));
    rotateY(radians(rotatevalue));
    box(50);
    popMatrix();
}
```

What is wrong that makes them to rotate differently?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.. both boxes seem to be rotating in the same way. To prove that, try putting the boxes right on top of each other.

Comment: Due to opengl perspective and big distance between them you are just experiencing optical illusion :)

Comment: Look at the screenshot guys, thats not an optical illusion. I am working with cinemizer glasses and while you are looking through them both pictures "merge" and u see the different movements.

Comment: Sorry I should put optical illusion inside quotes ... see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to using the OpenGL matrix stack, so this may be a little off-base.  I calculate my own model matrices to pass to the vertex shader.  When I do this, I do the rotations first before the translation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want draw 3D object inside 2D sketch you must use some type of projection same as your eye is projecting real world. For more information you should study more about [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)) and [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection).

So your boxes are rotating in the same way!  I will try to demonstrate it on this basic example. Here you can see 5 boxes around middle of sketch:

```java
void setup(){  
    size(500, 500, OPENGL);  
    fill(246, 225, 65);
    //ortho();
}

void draw(){
    background(245, 238, 184);   
    translate(width/2, height/2);    

    draw_box(0);
    draw_box(1);
    draw_box(2);
    draw_box(3);
    draw_box(4);
}

void draw_box(int pos){
    pushMatrix();       
    switch(pos){
      case 0: translate(   0,   0); break;
      case 1: translate(   0,-100); break;
      case 2: translate(   0, 100); break;
      case 3: translate( 100,   0); break;
      case 4: translate(-100,   0); break;
    }                  
    box(50);
    popMatrix();
}
```

There is no rotation so they should be same? NO! It is same as railway tracks = they are parallel but in long distance you can almost see them touching ([img](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#mediaviewer/File:Railroad-Tracks-Perspective.jpg))

You can try orthographic projection to get more similar boxes for more info see [ortho](https://www.processing.org/reference/ortho_.html). Also you should be more centric if you want better results.